# Can I use the same parameterized data for multiple test classes

Tags: java, automated-tests, junit4

I have a test class with parameterized data that's read in from an excel.
I want to created another test class using the same data but didn't want to have to create the fields all over again. is there a way for My test to share that parameterized data?

**Test Class 1**

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection excelData() throws IOException{
    Object[][] map = ExcelReader.retrieveExcelData();
    return Arrays.asList(map);
}

public TestClass1(Map<Object,Object> map){
    this.map = map;
    variable1 = map.get("Heading 1");
    variable2 = map.get("Heading 2");
}
```

Essentially I would have to do this process for every test class I create even though I'm using the same data, I am just performing different operations on it. I don't know if its possible to just have a base test with the parameterized data and have all the test classes use it so that I don't have to keep creating it.

Comment: Yes you can use the same

Comment: Why not just have it all in the same test class? You can inherit your test class from a base type, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it in two ways 
1. Import that package.class in other class
e.g Import packageName.TestClass1(must be public class)
2.You can inherit that class
e.g Classname extends TestClass1 and use all variables
Hope this help!